# web.config entry doesn't work in a specific site

Tags: asp.net, web-config

in my web.config file i've added an entry:

`<httpModules>

<add type="HDI.HTTPFilter" name="HTTPFilter"/>`

but the server where i've placed the website on is not reading this entry
but in other servers the site works perfectly.
what the problem might be?

thanks,
yishai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your servers have different operating systems and that's why they are giving diferent results.

In IIS6 (Windows Server 2003)

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
     <add type="HDI.HTTPFilter" name="HTTPFilter"/>
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

In II7 (Windows Server 2008) you will need to put your module inside `<system.webServer>`

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add type="HDI.HTTPFilter" name="HTTPFilter"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```